# Tabhost number of tabwidget

Tags: android, android-tabhost

n my application using Tab host FragmentActivity. While the application run on emulator i would like ti show only 4 tabhost and scroll other.

Please tell me what's the problem and How to resolve it.

Comment: First tell us what is the problem? Did you get any error? Show your logcat.

Comment: i havent any error but my problem is how to fixe the default number of tabhost for exemple when i start my application i would like to show only 4 tabhost out of 6 and scroll the other to show

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904806/adding-scroll-in-tabhost-in-android

Comment: Add your Tab widget in Horizontal scrollview.

Comment: the scroll is ok but the number of default tabhost depend of resolution çof screen